# Google Query Explorer Remove | From Results

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-query-language, google-analytics-filters

I am using query explorer to get data from GA and have been unsuccessful at removing the | from a column of results. My results end up like this:

- Points_Guy|442
- Bronn|434

The dimension I use is ga:eventLabel and I've tried filtering it numerous different ways to have it only return results like:

- Points_Guy
- Bronn

Some methods I've tried:

```
`ga:eventLabel=~([|]) search and replace with blank
`ga:eventLabel=~^Bronn\|$ ends with pipe
`ga:eventLabel=@Bronn|$
```

And a lot of others to that effect. Is it even possible to filter out results like that? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No, that's not how filters work in the API - they do not change the resulting strings, they change what your query will return. You will have to loop over the results and search and replace there.

Comment: Try to use Spreadsheet add-on (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/spreadsheet-add-on/) to get the same result as the Query Explorer in a Google Sheets so you can then manage the labels with formulas like in Excel.